NextJS TypeError: fetch failed. code: 'ECONNREFUSED' from Docker
I am running a Next.js app on Docker. However, when calling my API I get the following error
TypeError: fetch failed
   at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13178:13
   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
   at async m (/app/.next/server/chunks/961.js:3:716)
   at async b (/app/.next/server/pages/user/administration.js:51:1030)
   at async e3 (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.prod.js:31:594)
   at async doRender (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1425:30)
   at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1599:28)
   at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1507:28)
   at async NextNodeServer.renderPageComponent (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1924:24)
   at async NextNodeServer.renderToResponseImpl (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_@babel+core@7.24.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_sass@1.75.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1962:32) {
 [cause]: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
     at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1118:18)
     at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1685:7)
     at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]

This only happens when calling the API from getServerSideProps. Calling it from the client side, everything works as expected, including authenticated and public API calls.
The API is built with .NET Core and running on localhost:5068 (not in Docker). The Next app is running on localhost:3050 from Docker.
Everything works as expected when I run the Next app locally. So I'm assuming I need some configuration somewhere in Next (or .NET API) to make a successful call from getServerSideProps when Next is running in Docker context.
Dockerfile
FROM node:22.4-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile

FROM base AS builder
ENV NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE true
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ROOT_URI http://localhost:5068
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URI http://localhost:3050
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3050
ENV PORT 3050
CMD HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" node server.js

Docker Compose
services:
  sweetnotes.fe:
    image: myimage
    container_name: mycontainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3050:3050'


By default, Docker containers run on a Docker virtual network created by Docker to isolate the containers from the host. For network purposes, you can think of each container as a separate machine. And localhost in a container means the container itself.
To reach the host from a container, you need to add the host to the known hostnames of the container using extra_hosts in your compose file. It's common to use the name host.docker.internal as the hostname of the host.
In your case, it'd look like this
services:
  sweetnotes.fe:
    image: myimage
    container_name: mycontainer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3050:3050'
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'

Then you can change the URL of the backend to
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ROOT_URI http://host.docker.internal:5068

in your Dockerfile and it should work after rebuilding the image.

Thanks. Adding extra_hosts and changing the backend uri to http://host.docker.internal:5068 does solve the issue when Next calls the API server side from getServerSideProps.
However, client-side stopped working. I had to create two environment variables, one to use server-side and one client-side, and handle accordingly in the JS code. NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_CLIENT_SIDE_ROOT_URI http://localhost:5068 and NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVER_SIDE_ROOT_URI http://host.docker.internal:5068
Do you know why this behavior?

That's because the client is running in a browser on the host machine. From there, the address is localhost. The container is running on a docker bridge network and from there, the host has a different address.

Makes sense. Thanks a lot!

@HansKilian Hey Hans, I'm having a similar problem and would really appreciate your help. The only difference is I want to run both my backend and my frontend in the same docker container.
With the frontend not running the docker container, everything works as expected. When in the container, I get the a similar error to esausilva's.
My backend is localhost:8080. I need to reach /games and /leaderboard. Fetch fails for both.
This https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/68564 will explain more in depth.
